# onmouseover event on a button

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML and javascript. I have written below code to execute over() of javascript when the mouse hovers over a button but the code is not working.

Kindly suggest some changes in the code to get the it running.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function over()
        {
            document.getElementById("b1").value="You have hovered mouse over me";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onmouseover="over()" id="b1">Hover mouse over me</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace text with innerHTML
like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function over()
        {
            document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML="You have hovered mouse over me";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onmouseover="over()" id="b1">Hover mouse over me</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `innerHTML` of `button` element

```
document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = "You have hovered mouse over me";
```

Your script works on `<input type="button">`

Answer (score 0):

Your code **does work**.

The thing is, you will not see `value` change anywhere in the DOM. for that you should use `<input type='submit' value='Hover mouse over me'/>` instead, or change `innerHTML` of your `<button>` if you want to use a `<button>`.

`.innerHTML` on `<button>`

```js
function over()
{
    document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = "You have hovered mouse over me";
}
```

```html
<button id="b1" onmouseenter="over()">Hower me</button>
```

`value` on `<input type="submit">`

```js
function over()
{
    document.getElementById("b1").value = "You have hovered mouse over me";
}
```

```html
<input id="b1" type="submit" onmouseenter="over()" value="Hower me">
```